# How to set up a rails app, then set up a subdomain that uses all of the same code, except a different database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, subdomain

How to set up a rails app, then set up a subdomain that uses all of the same code, except a different database?

The implementation will be a front-end testing suite that utilizes all of the same url routes for slow testing, and will simultaneously test front and back end.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates just did some good screencasts on multitenacy where he covers subdomain switching based on scopes...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes

...and DB schemas...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql

I know these are premium/paid episodes but its good info if you are willing to spend $9/month. You mention switching databases, but you may be able to accomplish the same thing by either switching scopes, or schemas. You can check out the git repos for these episodes for free...

https://github.com/railscasts/388-multitenancy-with-scopes

https://github.com/railscasts/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql

...and do some reverse engineering to get a better understanding of domain switching. If you want to switch databases rather than schemas, I think the underlying logic will be the same.

As rewritten mentioned, this is all advanced development and you are unlikely to find a step by step tutorial for topics like this.

Comment: the answer is like "go to library, find the book, read it, and know what you need to know. Good luck!" :\